# JQL for this condition

Tags: jira, jql

how would the *JQL* look like for this condition?:

Generate a report of all HIGH severity JIRA tickets for a project with key X (or name X) that were created from 9 PM EST to 12 AM EST from the start of the year?

I tried something like :

```
Project = X AND Severity = "HIGH" AND created > "2015/01/01 21:00" and created < "2015/09/09",
```

but I need only those issues that are created between *9 PM* and *12 AM* everyday, from the beginning of the year.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there seems to be no tool to *get the hour from created date* but you can workaround it.

My two ideas are:

- find these tickets directly on Jira database (if you have access) it should be very easy since there are functions like *hour* (mySQL) or truncate (postgres)
- prepare JQL filter using some **generator script** - it is definetely less comfortable but possible to achieve even when you have not acces to database. The worst thing is that Jira filter fields **accepts only 2000 characters string** so you would need to copy that filter few lines by few lines.

  Little crazy but ok - it works so what's the idea? The idea is to use **startOfYear()** JQL function and its *offset version**. For example:

  ```
  created >= startOfYear(21h) and created < startOfYear(24h)
  ```

  will give you all tickets from **1 Jan 21:00 - 2 Jan 00:00**

  then you can use this Python script:

  ```
  step = 27
  maxDay = 1

  while maxDay <= 365 + step:
      maxDay += step

      output = "project = X and Severity = HIGH and ("

      for i in range(maxDay-step, maxDay):
          output += " (created >= startOfYear(" + str( ( (i-1) * 24 ) + 21) + "h) and created < startOfYear(" + str(i*24) + "h)) or"

      output = output[:-3]
      output += ")"

      print output
      print
  ```

  which will generate you set of JQL requests to copy-paste and execute (it is actually 15 of them - you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/GrHHLvgh)). Every set bounds 28 days because of 2000 limit of filter input in Jira.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by writing a custom JQL function and then using that function with a JQL query, which fits well with our requirements :

created >= "2015-01-01" and created <= "2015-12-31" and issue in getIssuesForTimeRange("21", "24")